# Does buying from the spider bake sale end a Genocide run?

Tags: undertale

If I buy a spider donut or spider cider from the bake sale in Hotland, I'm not able to fight Muffet. Does this mean I've failed the Genocide Run?

I came up to Muffet and she did not initiate a fight, but thanked me for donating so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Assuming you're still on the Genocide route, purchasing an item from the bake sale will not shift you off of it. From the [wiki](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Muffet):

> Purchasing an item from the Hotland bake sale does not abort the Genocide Route. Muffet will mention that the protagonist donated, but she will still be suspicious of them and attack. If she is spared, the Genocide Route will be aborted.

As long as you don't Spare Muffet, you'll still be on track to finish your Genocide run.

This is also backed up in the [Genocide route wiki page](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Genocide_Route):

> Muffet does not show up for her bake sale. It is still possible to buy from the bake sale, but this does not prevent the fight with Muffet. Before she is fought, she does not consider the protagonist to be fit to eat but attempts to dispose of them regardless.

Comment: The thing is, I went up to Muffet and she just said that I had donated so much, and thanked me. She never initiated a fight.

Comment: Beat me by a handful of seconds... Curses upon this mobile app and the difficulty in linking wikis... :)

Comment: @iMooshroom Was she standing at her bake sale stand in Hotland? If so, you were already shifted back to the Neutral route before facing her.

Comment: Hmmm, I remember killing everything I saw... but ok

Comment: @iMooshroom since there is a limited number of enemies, it may be worth to keep count. There's also a prompt that shows up if you've killed everything in an area that tells you no one is left. If you're not on the Genocide route anymore, it wasn't from buying from the bake sale.

Comment: @iMooshroom the Genocide Run is about more than killing everything you see, but killing everything that exists.  It's dark like that.